# PS4 external hard drive for game updates?

Tags: ps4

So I have a PS4 with the 500 gb hard drive and all from 2014 when they were being first released, and as of late I have had to delete updates for games (NOT dlc's / add-ons ) so I could update games or download a new one because I am lacking space. I have a good 7 games that I really like to play and rotate them through often  enough that deleting the updates isn't logical or worth it as I have 5mb/s Internet at best. Is there anyway to connect an external hard drive via USB and move games /updates back a forth? Or is there any way to buy a hard drive and install it?  Thanks all!

Comment: IIRC the PS4 can take any laptop HDD. You can even swap out your stock HDD for a SSD which can lead to a small decrease in load times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PS4 hard drive needs to meet the following requirements:

- 2.5 inch HDD
- 9.5mm tall (ie, depth)
- SATA connection

Most laptop-style drives should be ok.

Steps to upgrade hard drive: https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5107/~/upgrade-ps4-hdd